# SSMS cannot open a folder

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have an MVC app with a database that is saved in C:/Users/USERNAME. I want to open it in SSMS via attach. When I browse in that folder location it appears empty because SSMS can't read it.

How can I give SSMS permission to see that folder or how can I make my MVC app read the database from another folder? I know questions about this have been asked before but they are all from 2012 and vaguely explained so I can't make much use of them.

Or, if it's easier is there another way to open a database that works on my MVC app in SSMS?

Comment: You don't *open* a database in SSMS, it's just an IDE, you `ATTACH` or `RESTORE` it to a instance. It's not a file you read.

Comment: You have to grant permissions to the folder to the SQL Server service account.

Comment: `they are all from 2012 and vaguely explained so I can't make much use of them.` this hasn't changed and is very well explained in the docs and articles. SQL Server databases aren't "saved" as if they were files. What you describe is a user-instance database, a feature of SQL Server Express that became obsolete around 2012-2014 as it offers little benefit beyond development. In production, a user-instance database is far heavier than the same database hosted on a regular SQL Server edition, so hosters stopped offering them or eventually started charging *more* for them

Comment: In development it's easier to use LocalDB, another feature of SQL Server Express

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am using LocalDB but i have to deploy the app in LAN for school and deployment in LAN doesn't work properly with DB unless i make some settings with ssms that i cant access because it doesnt have permission.